# How to pass a variable in dir() in python

Tags: python, directory

How can I pass a class as a variable to dir() function in python?

I am trying to take user_defined attributes to what goes inside the dir() function

```
p = dir(sv.socket0.uncore.kar)
```

instead of absolute path shown above, I want to pass a variable which will have path

```
dir_path = 'sv.socket0.uncore' + '.kar' // kar here is user_defined

p = dir(dir_path)
```

Problem here is that the function considers the variable as string and not class and doesn't return all the class attributes.

Comment: Maybe `x = sv.socket0.uncore; dir(x)`

Comment: `'sv.socket0.uncore'` is a string. You just want `dir_path = sv.socket0.uncore`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to pass classes as arguments. If you do that you can also instantiate it and call `dir` on the new instance. In other words, instead of using a string with the path coded in it, you may want to pass a class variable:

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        return "bar"

def dir_cls(cls):
    return dir(cls())

print(dir_cls(Foo))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look but doesnt work what I want to do. I updated the explanation.